# conversion from matlab to python

Tags: python, matlab, matrix

I need to convert a matlab file to python.In matlab we have

```
for o_indy = 1:o_vres
  for o_indx = 1:o_hres
   ....
  if(condition)
    img_o(o_indy, o_indx,:) = pix11*p11 + pix12*p12 + pix21*p21 + pix22*p22;
```

where `pix11*p11 , pix12*p12 , pix21*p21 , pix22*p22` are `1x1x3 matrices`

output `img_o` in matlab is a `320x320x3 matrix`

when i converted to python

```
 for o_indy in range(1, o_vres+1):
    for o_indx in range(1, o_hres+1):
 ....
      if(condition):
        img_o[o_indy-1: o_indx] =(matrix((array(pix11)*p11))+matrix((array(pix12)*p12))+matrix((array(pix21)*p21))+matrix((array(pix22)*p22)))
```

i am getting a matrix of `1x320x960` size.
How can i fix this?

Comment: If haven't seen it already, this will probably help you: http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users Also isn't  `img_o[o_indy-1: o_indx]` missing a comma somewhere?

Comment: What is the shape of `pix11` and `p11`? How was `img_o` initialized? What shape did it have?

Comment: pix11 is `1x1x3 matrix`, and `p11` is a constant. `img_o` is initialised as `img_o = tile(temp_fill_value, osize)` .where `temp_fill_value = array(fill_value)` and `fill_value = [[[0, 0, 0]]]`.`osize` is the dimension of the image to be converted

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues here.

First, you are using slices, rather than indexing.  It should be the same as matlab, just with () replaced with []:

```
img_o[o_indy, o_indx, :]
```

Second, python uses 0-based indexing, not 1-based indexing like Matlab.  So you should do range(o_vres), for example.

Third, you really shouldn't be using matrices at all.

So what your code should look like is this:

```
pix11=array(pix11)
pix12=array(pix12)
pix13=array(pix13)
for o_indy in range(o_vres):
    for o_indx in range(o_hres):
 ....
      if(condition):
        img_o[o_indy, o_indx, :] = pix11*p11+pix12*p12+pix2*p21+pix22*p22
```

There is also a problem with how you how you are tiling.  If osize has a length of 2, then the resulting array will be wrong.  So say osize is (320, 320), then

tile(temp_fill_value, osize)

will result in array of shape (1, 320, 960)

So you would need osize to have a length of 3, with the last value being 1.  So, say:

```
img_o = tile(temp_fill_value, [osize[0], osize[1], 1])
```

which results in an array of shape (320, 320, 3)

However, the simpler solution is just:

```
img_o = np.zeros([osize[0], osize[1], 3])
```